# Limit db user permission on google cloud sql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to Google Cloud SQL. I created two postgres DBs with two new users (one created from web dashboard and one created from commandline). My goal is to prevent the two users to be able to modify each other DB, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is what I want:

- UserA all privileges on DB_A
- UserA no privileges on DB_B
- UserB all privileges on DB_B
- UserB no privileges on DB_A

I already tried to grant/revoke permissions from psql prompt, but in the end I still be able to create/drop tables in DB_A as UserB.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Postgres on Cloud SQL is standard Postgres, so it's just like any other Postgres instance:

To give a role all privileges:

```
GRANT ALL ON <db_name> TO <role_name>;
```

To remove all privileges:

```
REVOKE ALL ON <db_name> TO <role_name>;
```

The Postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/privileges.html) on privileges does give the follow caveat for:

> The special privileges of an object's owner (i.e., the right to modify
>   or destroy the object) are always implicit in being the owner, and
>   cannot be granted or revoked

So keep that in mind - if UserA owns both databases, they can always modify them.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work: I created all databases/users through the "postgres" user and then granted/revoked permissions as needed, but the problem still there.

Comment: It is explained in the [link provided](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/privileges.html) in the answer above: _The special privileges of an object's owner (i.e., the right to modify or destroy the object) are always implicit in being the owner, and cannot be granted or revoked. But the owner can choose to revoke his own ordinary privileges, for example to make a table read-only..._ You can modify the tables as UserB or UserA because basically you are the owner of the objects created. Try to have the people to whom you'll assing those roles make the modifications and see what happens.